# Magento 2: How to hide an HTML element in the checkout page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, shipping-methods, datepicker

I have a `datepicker` block on the checkout shipping step that I would like to be able to hide based on a condition. If the user doesn't qualify for a certain shipping method, I would like for the `datepicker` to be hidden. I tried adding this logic to the js file associated with the `datepicker` block, but nothing worked.

**HTML**

```
<div class="date-wrapper" id="date-wrapper" >
<label class="label">Delivery Date</label>
<div class="control">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datepicker: true"  name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" readonly="true"/>
</div>

<label class="label">Comment</label>
<div class="control">
    <textarea name="delivery_comment" id="delivery_comment" ></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</br>
```

**JS**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'SR_DeliveryDate/delivery-date-block'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var disabled = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.disabled;
            var noday = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.noday;
            //var hourMin = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMin);
            //var hourMax = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMax);
            var format = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.format;

            if(!format) {
                format = 'yy-mm-dd';
            }
            var disabledDay = disabled.split(",").map(function(item) {
                return parseInt(item, 10);
            });

            ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                    var $el = $(element);
                    //initialize datetimepicker
                    if(noday) {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format

                        };
                    } else {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format,
                            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var day = date.getDay();
                                if(disabledDay.indexOf(day) > -1) {
                                    return [false];
                                } else {
                                    return [true];
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    $el.datepicker(options);

                    var writable = valueAccessor();
                    if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                        var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                        if (propWriters && propWriters.datepicker) {
                            writable = propWriters.datepicker;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    writable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
                    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                    if (widget) {
                        var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        widget.date(date);
                    }
                }
            };

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you can call one method which return it is visible or not.

**JS**

```
define([
'jquery',
'ko',
'uiComponent' 
],function ($, ko, Component) {
'use strict';

return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'SR_DeliveryDate/delivery-date-block'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this._super();
        var disabled = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.disabled;
        var noday = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.noday;
        //var hourMin = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMin);
        //var hourMax = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMax);
        var format = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.format;
    this.showDatepicker(disabled);
        if(!format) {
            format = 'yy-mm-dd';
        }
        var disabledDay = disabled.split(",").map(function(item) {
            return parseInt(item, 10);
        });

        ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                var $el = $(element);
                //initialize datetimepicker
                if(noday) {
                    var options = {
                        minDate: 0,
                        dateFormat:format

                    };
                } else {
                    var options = {
                        minDate: 0,
                        dateFormat:format,
                        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                            var day = date.getDay();
                            if(disabledDay.indexOf(day) > -1) {
                                return [false];
                            } else {
                                return [true];
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }

                $el.datepicker(options);

                var writable = valueAccessor();
                if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                    var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                    if (propWriters && propWriters.datepicker) {
                        writable = propWriters.datepicker;
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                writable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
                //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                if (widget) {
                    var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                    widget.date(date);
                }
            }
        };

        return this;
    },
   showDatepicker:function () {
        //put your condition here. I assumed this as your condition
        var disabled = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.disabled;
         //if disabled return false to not to show block else return true to display        
        if(disabled){
           return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    },
  });
});
```

**Now in your HTML Template**

```
<!-- ko if: (showDatepicker()) -->
<div class="date-wrapper" id="date-wrapper" >
<label class="label">Delivery Date</label>
<div class="control">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datepicker: true"  name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" readonly="true"/>
</div>

<label class="label">Comment</label>
<div class="control">
    <textarea name="delivery_comment" id="delivery_comment" ></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</br>
<!-- /ko -->
```

After that you need to clear cache and deploy static content.

Comment: Say I have a global PHP variable from a model file, can I call it within the JS function? I tried assigning a php value to a javascript variable within that script and it seems to accept only strictly JS/JQuery. I ask this because I need to hide the block based on a PHP response from the collectrates function in my shipping module

Comment: Yes you can do it also but for that you need to call that controller which will return that

Comment: Well thank you very much. You have helped me out greatly